# Adding / Joining multiple strings without effect of "\n" python

Tags: python, string

Please suggest a python code to perform the following operation :

s1 = "a\nb\nc"

s2 = "d\ne\nf"

Normally adding s1 + "->" + s2 we get

```
a

b

c->d

e

f
```

I want the output as

```
a->d

b  e

c  f
```

Also should work with multiple strings

Another example

```
  DT=['Parents\n|\n|\n|\n|---> Yes ---> Cinema',
      'No',
      'Weather\n|\n|\n|---> Sunny ---> Tennis\n|\n|---> Rainy --> Cinema',
      'Windy',
      'Money\n|\n|---> Rich ---> Cinema\n|\n|---> Poor ---> Cinema',
      'No',
      'Windy']
```

I want to print

```
 Parents ---> No ---> Weather ---> Windy ---> Money
 |                    |                       |
 |                    |                       |---> Rich ---> Cinema 
 |                    |---> Sunny ---> Tennis |
 |---> Yes ---> Cinema|                       |---> Poor ---> Cinema
                      |---> Rainy ---> Cinema
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to split your strings on newlines, zip the result, then rejoin with spaces and newlines

Comment: Do you really only want `->` between `a` and `d`, or do you want `a->d`, `b->e`, and `c->f` on three separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

#### Split, Zip, Join

Use `.split` on the "\n" character to yield two separate lists of one-line strings.

Then `zip()` them together to get a *list of pairs* of strings. You want to put together each pair into a single string with a `->` between them.

Then `.join()` the one-line strings together with `\n` characters in between.

```
s1 = "a\nb\nc"
s2 = "d\ne\nf"

result = "\n".join([
  a+"->"+b for a,b in zip(
    s1.split("\n"),
    s2.split("\n"))
])

print(result)
```

#### To accommodate multiple strings

```
s1 = "a\nb\nc"
s2 = "d\ne\nf"
s3 = "g\nh\ni"
multiline_strings = [s1,s2,s3]

result = "\n".join([
  "->".join(one_line_strings) for one_line_strings in zip(
    *[multiline_string.split("\n") for multiline_string in multiline_strings]    
  )
])

print(result)
```

Comment: Can you please help me with second example mentioned. Thank You